# How to offload all the documents of an elastic search index into a json file?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

`cURL xGET` is one of the option used. It has limitations on the size of document pulled (limited to 2gb output). Tried with the scroll option in `xget` too.
Both the option brings the node down.

ES version: 6.1

Is there any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

The way to export all the data is by using the scroll API, which allows you to get the data in pages using scroll_id:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html

You can also check logstash: input from elasticsearch, output to file.

Comment: Using `scroll` returns `Gateway Time-out`

Comment: You can increase the scroll timeout, which defaults to 1m. By using the 'scroll' parameter and set it to 5m or more.

Comment: Another option is to decrease the page size you are processing, so that each page will get processed faster and the timeout won't reach